# Cleaning staff aboard star ships

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager

Did the Enterprise, Voyager or DS9 have a cleaning crew and janitorial staff? Or is it like the Japanese where everyone would devote time to clean? Or do you think they use the transporters to beam the dirt off ship or whatever mess they have to clean at the time? I wonder if they had space age Roombas like in Star Wars.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mh8y0yEwtf0